# Parse query not correctly comparing

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

What I want to do is run a query in my Parse cloud code that compares the two contents of the `top2` array to the `categoryId` property of every `userCategory` object associated with a User. When I run this code however, it doesn't properly find matches, despite the fact that there are matches in the database.

I think the issue lies here:

```
      query.containedIn('categoryId', top2);
      query.equalTo('User', Parse.User.current())
```

I think that maybe `categoryId` isn't the correct one to use. I'm also not entirely sure about the second line, as it seems like that would compare `top2` to  the User object, not instances of the userCategory object that's associated with it.

Full code:

```
// Query sent from search bar

Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function(request, response) {
          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: url,
      params: {     
       'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords', 
       'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
       'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
       'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
       'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
       'itemFilter(0).name=ListingType' : 'itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice',
       'keywords' : request.params.item,

     },
      success: function (httpResponse) {


  // parses results

          var httpresponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
          var items = [];

          httpresponse.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.forEach(function(itemByKeywordsResponse) {
            itemByKeywordsResponse.searchResult.forEach(function(result) {
              result.item.forEach(function(item) {
                items.push(item);
              });
            });
          });


  // count number of times each unique primaryCategory shows up (based on categoryId), returns top two IDs and their respective names


          var categoryIdResults = {};

          // Collect two most frequent categoryIds
          items.forEach(function(item) {
            var id = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryId;
            if (categoryIdResults[id]) categoryIdResults[id]++;
            else categoryIdResults[id] = 1;
          });

          var top2 = Object.keys(categoryIdResults).sort(function(a, b) 
            {return categoryIdResults[b]-categoryIdResults[a]; }).slice(0, 2);
          console.log('Top category Ids: ' + top2.join(', '));


          var categoryNameResults = {};

          // Collect two most frequent categoryNames  
          items.forEach(function(item) {
            var categoryName = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryName;
            if (categoryNameResults[categoryName]) categoryNameResults[categoryName]++;
            else categoryNameResults[categoryName] = 1;
          });  


          var top2Names = Object.keys(categoryNameResults).sort(function(a, b) 
            {return categoryNameResults[b]-categoryNameResults[a]; }).slice(0, 2);
          console.log('Top category Names: ' + top2Names.join(', '));



  // compare categoryIdResults to userCategory object

          //Extend the Parse.Object class to make the userCategory class
          var userCategory = Parse.Object.extend("userCategory");

          //Use Parse.Query to generate a new query, specifically querying the userCategory object.
          query = new Parse.Query(userCategory);

          //Set constraints on the query.
          query.containedIn('categoryId', top2);
          query.equalTo("User", Parse.User.current())

          //Submit the query and pass in callback functions.
          var isMatching = false;
          query.find({
            success: function(results) {
              var userCategoriesMatchingTop2 = results;
              console.log("userCategory comparison success!");
              console.log(results);
              if (userCategoriesMatchingTop2 && userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length > 0) {
                isMatching = true;
              }

              response.success({
                "results": [
                  { "Number of top categories": top2.length },
                            { "Top category Ids": top2 },
                            { "Top category names": top2Names },   
                         { "Number of matches": userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length }, 
         { "User categories that match search": userCategoriesMatchingTop2 }
                ]
              });

              console.log('User categories that match search: ' + results)
            },
            error: function(error) {
              //Error Callback
              console.log("An error has occurred");
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
  },
          error: function (httpResponse) {
              console.log('error!!!');
              response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
          }
     });
});
```

userCategory structure:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("userCategoryCreate", function(request, response) {
    var userCategory = Parse.Object.extend("userCategory");
    var newUserCategory = new userCategory();
    newUserCategory.set("categoryId", "");
    newUserCategory.set("minPrice");
    newUserCategory.set("maxPrice");
    newUserCategory.set("itemCondition");
    newUserCategory.set("itemLocation");
    newUserCategory.set("parent", Parse.User.current());
    newUserCategory.save({ 

      success: function (){
        console.log ('userCategory successfully created!');
        response.success('Request successful');
      },

      error: function (){
        console.log('error!!!');
      response.error('Request failed');
      }

    });
});
```

Logs:

```
I2014-05-13T18:11:25.243Z] v169: Ran cloud function eBayCategorySearch for user jKs5QpXjpd with:
  Input: {"item":"iphone 5 16gb"}
  Result: {"results":[{"Number of top categories":1},{"Top category Ids":["9355"]},{"Top category names":["Cell Phones & Smartphones","Mobile & Smart Phones"]},{"Number of matches":0},{"User categories that match search":[]}]}
I2014-05-13T18:11:26.530Z] Top category Ids: 9355
I2014-05-13T18:11:26.531Z] Top category Names: Cell Phones & Smartphones, Mobile & Smart Phones
I2014-05-13T18:11:26.633Z] userCategory comparison success!
I2014-05-13T18:11:26.633Z] []
I2014-05-13T18:11:26.633Z] User categories that match search:
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of your userCategory class in Parse and the log output when running the cloud code function?

Comment: Sure, just edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to match against a field that doesn't exist. Based on the create code,

```
query.equalTo('User', Parse.User.current())
```

should be

```
query.equalTo('parent', Parse.User.current())
```